# Promise "remember" value from previous execution

Tags: javascript, events, promise

I'm working with promises. I execute my promise method:

```
async gotoMap(page, expectedStartName, endMap) {
        let someArray = [{x: 12, y: 15}, {x: 23, y: 56}];
        await goTo.init(page, someArray[0].x, someArray[0].x.y);
        console.log('After first map.');
        await checkIfWeWentThrough(); //other async method, irrelevant
        await goTo.init(page, someArray[1].x, someArray[1].y);
        console.log('After second map.');
    }
},
```

Code of `goTo.init` method:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    eventBus.on('start::goto', async() => {
        console.log('start::goto');
        await this.goto(page, x, y);
        if (await waitForCoords(page, x, y)) {
            console.log('we achieve goal');
            resolve();
        } else {
            console.log('emit start::goto inner');
            eventBus.emit('start::goto');
        }
    });
    console.log('emit start::goto outer');
    eventBus.emit('start::goto');
});
```

It console.log 'we achieve goal' so I expect that first execution is completed, resolved and gone.

After I execute this method second time (after lets say 20 seconds but almost immeditely after first execution finished), thanks to consoles logs from `waitForCoords`, I can still see it running with parameters(arguments) from first execution.

Except that I see that there are more and more console.logs. After a minute of running it, this method multiple so many times that it spam with consoles every few miliseconds. But this happen only **after second execution** of `goTo.init`. Before that it doesn't seems to multiply.

I don't get it. Why it is still running with old parameters although I resolved it? Why this method is multiplied?

Code of `waitForCoords` which is in if statement is:

```
return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
    let timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(false);
    }, 3000);
    console.log(x,y);
    await page.waitForFunction(`
        window.hero.x === ${x} && window.hero.y === ${y}
    `);
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    resolve(true);
});
```

So it resolves false every 3 sec and resolve true after something is completed (puppeteer method which execute js in page context but I think it doesn't matter).

---

**Edit**: I additionally add clear timeout to the `waitForCoords` method so it will not resolve false after it resolves true. Anyway my issue is still same - behavior didn't change at all.

Comment: Please provide the full declaration of the function, especially where the `x` and `y` variables come from. Also post the full code that calls `goTo.init` and where `someArray` comes from.

Comment: You should never pass an `async function` as a callback - not to `eventBus.on` and not to `new Promise`.

Comment: What is `page.waitForFunction` and why are you dealing with strings of code there?

Comment: The variables are correct values for sure. `page.waitForFunction` is puppeteer (something like selenium) method which execute javascript in page context (within the web app which I'm testing). I'll update question with code where I'm calling `goTo.init` in a second. What do you mean that I should never pass async function as a callback?

Comment: Just edited. It is very nested code I'm trying to keep question clean.

Comment: So basically I shouldn't be using custom events when dealing with promises? I don't understand.

Comment: "*this method multiple so many times*" - your problem seems to be that you don't remove the `start::goto` handler from the shared `eventBus` when you resolve the promise, so it runs again when you emit events the second time. Why are you even using that event bus, is something else listening for these events as well? Otherwise just use a recursive function, or a `while` loop with `async`/`await`.

Comment: What does `this.goto()` do?

Comment: Thank you bergi. You maybe didn't give real solution but point out that this event loop is unnecessary so I rewrite entire thing. I didn't use while loop because it seems to execute more than one for 3 seconds but I simply used interval. I also was emiting this event from other place indeed, but I just import needed functions there as well. Now, should I post answer with rewritten code or just delete question?

Comment: I guess [posting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is the right choice